# How can one find a plaintext, given n, e, and ciphertext (using RSA)?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I've looked into the RSA algorithms but it doesn't seem to be possible? I've only seen one other post like this and there were no answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since e is the encryption key, the short answer, you cannot break RSA if there is no weakness on the parameters.

Here an example for some attack that might interest you;

If the message space is small, and there is no padding, you can perform searching by encrypting all possible plaintext and comparing them with the ciphertext.

[here](http://www.members.tripod.com/irish_ronan/rsa/attacks.html) a more complete list;

Comment: Well if the e is something small like 3, (n and ciphertext are still large) is it possible?

Comment: By having small message space, you can try to find the message, not the decryption key. actually, a gave you only one of the problem. the small public key is not the problem on this attack. if the message space is small, it works for every public key.

Answer (score 0):

Though this may not be correct or it is just taking a very long time (likely from a huge n), I found this (using Java for its BigInteger);

Given: n = big number, e = 3, c = big number (ciphertext)
Find: m (plaintext)

We know m = (c^d)mod(n) and ed mod(phi) = 1, so we can derive the following (using BigInteger notation):

First of all, we know that Euler made the Totient Function, so by implementing the code from HotJar, we will be able to make this:

```
BigInteger m = c.modPow(e.modInverse(phi(n)), n); //This is in BigInteger Notation
```

From HotJar, but changed by me to fit the data-typing:

```
public static BigInteger gcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) 
{ 
    if (a.equals(new BigInteger("0"))) 
        return b; 
    return gcd(b.mod(a), a); 
} 

// A simple method to evaluate 
// Euler Totient Function 
public static BigInteger phi(BigInteger n) 
{ 
    BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1"); 

    for(BigInteger i = new BigInteger("2"); i.compareTo(n) == (-1); i = i.add(new BigInteger("1")))
        if(gcd(i, n).equals(new BigInteger("1")))
            result = result.add(new BigInteger("1"));
    return result; 
}
```